# How to view soft subtitles in VLC player

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I have created a video file with soft subtitles. These subtitles are visible in Windows Media Player, but they are not visible in VLC.

What can I do? Do I have to create a `-.srt` file specifically for VLC player?

Edit:

I have not used any subtitle file or format. I have expression encoder to add a "soft subtitle" to the video

```
TimeSpan midpoint = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, temp);
mergedVideo.ScriptCommands.Add(new Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.ScriptCommand(midpoint, "caption", DataLogFiles[j]));
```

This adds the subtitle or caption as meta data. This is visible in Windows media player.

Comment: What video container? Which subtitle format did you use?

Comment: The question remains, which video container? If you use Expression Encoder, I'm guessing it does some Windows-specific stuff…

Answer (score 0):

No, VLC supports `.srt` files. VLC player will load `.srt` files **if the movie and `.srt` file are in the same folder**.

Ensure that the `.srt` file and movie are in the same folder and play the movie. VLC will auto-pick the `.srt` file and it will display the subtitles.

Comment: right now there is no subtitle file. i.e. it is soft subtitle embedded as meta data in the video itself. VLC does not support this is it?